# validate HTML rendering on extjs textboxes

Tags: extjs4

In EXT JS, I have HTML Decoder as renderer for text. My requirement is that this should work only when the content is a valid html.

eg: if content is < I> asdf < / I> (valid one), it should get rendered in Italics.
But if I give an invalid tag eg : < asdfasdf I am getting blank text box, since this is not valid HTML.

My requirement is to display < asdfasdf as it is, since it is not valid, and to display < I> asdf < / I> in Italics.

Can someone help please.

(Please note I have added spaces between tags so that my question gets displayed correctly here.)

Comment: Without your code, we are unable to help you. please post your code.

Comment: columns: [{Text: "announcement" renderer: "htmlDecode"}] I want this text to be displayed as it is (Without rendering) in case of invalid html, and valid html has to be rendered properly

Comment: Post full code please.

Comment: Am sorry, it is against my company policy to post code online(that results in termination :( ) That is the reason why I am not posting the actual code. But I have a code [{Text: "announcement" renderer: "htmlDecode"}]. This will display the text that user enters (Valid and invalid html tags) The requirement is to render valid html tags properly and display the text as such in case of invalid html tags.